# Percorrer valores do Enum em C

Tags: c, string, loop, enums

Tem alguma forma de percorrer os valores do `Enum` em C e exibir no formato *string*, como em Java, C# e outras linguagens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C é uma linguagem bem básica, não possui uma infraestrutura para facilitar a vida do programador. Sua filosofia é dar poder e flexibilidade, além de transparência do uso dos recursos, e não facilidade, então tem que se virar para obter o resultado que deseja. Uma forma simples é criar um *array* com os nomes nas mesmas posições da enumeração e usá-las:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //o DirecaoLast é só para determinar o final, só funciona se usar valores padrões
    typedef enum direcao { Norte, Sul, Leste, Oeste, DirecaoLast } Direcao;
    const char* DirecaoNames[] = { "Norte", "Sul", "Leste", "Oeste" };
    for (int i = 0; i < DirecaoLast; i++) {
        Direcao direcao = i;
        printf("%s = %d\n", DirecaoNames[i], direcao);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0Gehu1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/peqoamrg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ScanEnum.c).

[No SO tem uma solução que mantém os dois sincronizados](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966395/221800), mas sinceramente é uma complicação a toa.

Tem outras técnicas, algumas podem ser bem sofisticadas. Uma que pode ajudar no caso dos valores dos elementos da enumeração serem dispersos é ter algumas funções auxiliares que façam o laço para você tanto pegando valores, como nomes dos elementos, provavelmente passaria um ponteiro para função que teria o corpo do laço. Cada nova enumeração teria que ter um conjunto de funções com implementação própria tratando direito o que precisa. Provavelmente teria que usar `switch` para tratar cada elemento. Então está apenas criando uma abstração.

Pode até mesmo criar um sistema de reflexão próprio com um pré-compilador, mas ninguém faz isto. Se for tão importante, talvez seja o caso de ousar outra linguagem, mas nunca é tão necessário.

Comment: Não consegui usar aqui, tentei atribui um char *s[]; a uma enum de profissões,

Comment: Te mostrei funcionando, se tentou fazer e não conseguiu já é outro problema, pode abrir uma [nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) postando que fez pra gente ver onde errou especificamente neste caso. A solução geral, que foi o pedido, está dada.